# Apply regular expression with different string array using Regex

Tags: javascript, arrays, regex, string

I want to use different scenarios of the string matched and filter.

Ex:-

```
a = ['Rubico Fans Draw', 'David Rubico Fanch', 'Nikas Fans Farius']
```

I want out like this:-

```
'Rubico' 
o/p:- ['Rubico Fans Draw', 'David Rubico Richad']



'Fan'  
o/p:- ['Rubico Fans Draw', 'David Rubico Fanch', 'Nikas Fans Farius']



'Rubico Fans Draw' 
o/p:- ['Rubico Fans Draw']
```

Comment: Can you show your attempt? Also is the requirement of regular expression necessary? Like this can be done in a simpler way. The way I see, you want something like - Given an input, search an array and return all those elements that contain it. Is that understanding correct?

Comment: Please provide us with the solution you've been working on

Comment: 2 examples and 2 questions: function search(input) {
  return a.filter(i => i.includes(input));
}
console.log(search('Rubico'));

function searchRegex(input) {
  return a.filter(i => i.match(new RegExp(input, 'i')));
}
console.log(searchRegex('Rubico'));

Comment: Why do with regex? Or what my regex function in earlier comment is doing, is that the correct understanding?

Comment: @Perry: Please don't write so much code in a comment, it's hard to read.

Comment: To get this output I just have to use https://regexr.com/ as in the filter if even one character laughs its string has to be found.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
const items = ['Rubico Fans Draw', 'David Rubico Fanch', 'Nikas Fans Farius'];

const regex = /Rubico/;

const matchedItems = items.filter(item => item.search(regex) !== -1);

console.log(matchedItems);
```

Comment: ... using a RegExp's `test` method is/was more straightforward ... `items.filter(item => regex.test(item));`